# Value is Empty When read Asp.net TextBox Value in codebehind when i changed asp.net textvalue by ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

Value is Empty When read Asp.net TextBox Value  in codebehind when i changed asp.net textvalue by ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#=<%txtDatePicker.ClientID%>').datepicker();
                         });
</script>
```

...

```
 <Telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtDatePicker" RunAt="Server" > </Telerik:RadTextBox>
```

datepicker a ajax component that allow to user that select date from calender.when user select your date it paste that on txtdatepicker text.
txtdatepicker a asp.net textbox component.

so when i want to read   txtdatepicker.text in codebehind it result is empty.why?

Comment: Replace `$('#=<%txtDatePicker.ClientID%>').datepicker();` with `$('<%= txtDatePicker.ClientID %>').val();`

Comment: if remove keyword # .my calender doesn't show. so datepicker is a ajax calnder function.why must be replaced by val.val doesn't work

Comment: Try chrome console to see if there are some JS errors

Comment: can you paste your PageLoad method ?

Answer (score 0):

You had mistake in your code, try following, which can help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#<%=txtDatePicker.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: @Phoenix: Have you tried this yet?? I think it should work now.

Comment: Hay use web developer add-ons in Mozilla and try to find out what is the error, it will defiantly help you, and this is free...

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,ie remove '=' and '#='

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#<%txtDatePicker.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

This is the default method

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Seethis site http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

what about if you set the property ClientIDMode="Static" of your server side TextBox 
and then use datepicker as it is used default

```
$(function() {
$( "#YourTextBoxID" ).datepicker();
```

});